# How do I get Django forms to show the html required attribute?

Tags: django, forms, html

I have this form field:

```
email = forms.EmailField(
  required=True,
  max_length=100,
)
```

It has the required attribute, but in the html it is not adding the html attribute `required`. In fact it's not even using `email` as the field type, it's using `text`... though it appears to get max_length just fine.

Actual:

```
<input id="id_email" type="text" name="email" maxlength="100">
```

Expected:

```
<input id="id_email" type="email" name="email" maxlength="100" required="true">
```

How can I get Django to use the correct attributes in html forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monkeypatching Widget is your best bet:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Widget
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget
from django.forms import HiddenInput, FileInput

old_build_attrs = Widget.build_attrs

def build_attrs(self, extra_attrs=None, **kwargs):
    attrs = old_build_attrs(self, extra_attrs, **kwargs)

    # if required, and it's not a file widget since those can have files
    # attached without seeming filled-in to the browser, and skip hidden "mock"
    # fileds created for StackedInline and TabbedInline admin stuff
    if (self.is_required
            and type(self) not in (AdminFileWidget, HiddenInput, FileInput)
            and "__prefix__" not in attrs.get("name", "")):
        attrs['required'] = 'required'

    return attrs

Widget.build_attrs = build_attrs
```

Comment: Might I suggest that you change the if statement to read: `if self.is_required and type(self) not in (AdminFileWidget,HiddenInput, FileInput) and "__prefix__" not in attrs["name"]:` That'll prevent the browser from adding `required="true"` when an object already has a file attached to it, as well as skip the hidden "mock" fields created for StackedInline and TabbedInline admin stuff.

Answer (score 20):

Django form elements are written against `<input />` as it exists in HTML 4, where `type="text"` was the correct option for e-mail addresses. There was also no `required="true"`.

If you want custom HTML attributes, you need the `attrs` keyword argument to the *widget*. It would look something like this:

```
email = forms.EmailField(
    max_length=100,
    required=True,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'required': 'true' }),
)
```

You can check out more documentation about widgets [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/). Discussion of `attrs` is near the bottom of that page.

Regarding `type="email"`, you might be able to send that to your `attrs` dictionary and Django will intelligently override its default. If that isn't the result you get, then your route is to subclass `forms.TextInput` and then pass it to the `widget` keyword argument.

Comment: Is there a way to monkey patch the form widget base class? It seems very un-DRY to have to specify the required attribute twice.

Comment: I suppose. It's `django.forms.BaseForm`.

Answer (score 10):

Combining Daniel and Daniel answers, I usually use this mixin for my forms:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget
from django.forms.widgets import HiddenInput, FileInput


class HTML5RequiredMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HTML5RequiredMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            if (self.fields[field].required and
               type(self.fields[field].widget) not in
                    (AdminFileWidget, HiddenInput, FileInput) and 
               '__prefix__' not in self.fields[field].widget.attrs):

                    self.fields[field].widget.attrs['required'] = 'required'
                    if self.fields[field].label:
                        self.fields[field].label += ' *'
```

So when i have to create a new form or modelform i just use:

```
class NewForm(HTML5RequiredMixin, forms.Form):
    ...
```

Comment: In my case, I got  ' Form object has no attribute 'fields' ' because python evaluates '__init__' from left to right and form object wasn't available at the time of HTML5RequiredMixin '__init__' call.  After I change the order of class declaration like this and part of __init__ of NewForm it worked.  ' class NewForm(forms.Form, HTML5RequiredMixin) ' , then  __init__ of NewForm, call ' HTML5RequiredMixin.__init__ '

Answer (score 7):

Since Django 1.10, this is built-in.

From the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#forms):

> Required form fields now have the required HTML attribute. Set the new Form.use_required_attribute attribute to False to disable it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been having troubles setting this attribute for quite a long time.

Answer (score 6):

There's also the template-only solution using a filter. I recommend [`django-widget-tweaks`](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks):

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{{ form.email|attr:'required:true' }}
```

That was easy.

Answer (score 4):

As you've realized, setting your Field required attribute to `True` is only for backend validation, as explained in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#required).

What you really want is to add a required attribute to the [Widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/) of the field:

```
email.widget.attrs["required"] = "required"
```

But if you really want to write elegant, DRY code, you should make a base form class that dynamically looks for all your required fields and modifies their widget required attribute for you (you can name it whatever you wish, but "BaseForm" seems apt):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class BaseForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for bound_field in self:
            if hasattr(bound_field, "field") and bound_field.field.required:
                bound_field.field.widget.attrs["required"] = "required"
```

And then have all your Form objects descend from it:

```
class UserForm(BaseForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []

    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=100)
```