# How to add required attribute to a Django form field

Tags: python, django, html

I would like to have a Django form field render as:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

but when I try `username.widget.attrs['required'] = ''` I get something like:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required="">
```

Is there a way in which the standalone HTML5 attributes like `required` can be shown in the resulting HTML form?

I am using Django 1.6 on Python 2.6, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the `required` attribute in a valid format.

```
username.widget.attrs['required'] = 'required'
```

Take a look here for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012975/1566605

Comment: It would be useful to explain where this line should be added to those that are learning Django.

Answer (score 5):

@mariodev is correct. If you want a more elegant way to do this, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37738828/2812260 (relevant part copied below):

If you really want to write elegant, DRY code, you should make a base form class that dynamically looks for all your required fields and modifies their widget required attribute for you (you can name it whatever you wish, but "BaseForm" seems apt):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class BaseForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for bound_field in self:
            if hasattr(bound_field, "field") and bound_field.field.required:
                bound_field.field.widget.attrs["required"] = "required"
```

And then have all your Form objects descend from it:

```
class UserForm(BaseForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []

    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a declarative option on a per-form rather than a per-model basis this was my solution:

```
from django import forms

class RequiredFieldsModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequiredFieldsModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for bound_field in self:
            if (
                hasattr(bound_field, "field") and
                bound_field.name in self.Meta.required_fields
            ):
                bound_field.field.widget.attrs["required"] = "required"


# Your forms
class UserForm(RequiredFieldsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        required_fields = ['username']
        model = User
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set required attribute to widget like this:

> self.fields['field_name'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'required':'required'})

Comment: You should place this in __init__ method